# Carrinho de compras em iOS

Tags: ios

Estou começando em iOS e preciso fazer um carrinhos de compras para meu app. O que já tenho é uma searchbar onde é possível fazer a busca do produto e selecioná-lo. Feito isso, o mesmo abre em outra view. Minha idéia é ter um campo para adicionar a quantidade desejada e um buttom que some o valor com essa quantidade e passe para o carrinho. Enfim, algo comum em e-commerce mas que não sei por onde começar.
Desde já, agradeço.  Carlos

Comment: Bem vindo, veja como fazer uma boa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Antes de começar algum projeto, entenda mais sobre a linguagem e os frameworks envolvidos no desenvolvimento, assim fará sua vida e a dos seus usuários melhor